# @font imports on codepen css3 / html5

Tags: html, css

Ive been going crazy trying to find a font that is cursive. Like a classy cursive. I try to google "google import fonts" but most of the stuff do not make sense or when I add it to codepen, wont work.

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400');
@import url('http://mirokarilahti.com/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css');
```

an @import on a cursive type language? Is there a list or a website that shows. I tried googleapis.com

Comment: I just used your first `@import` statement in codepen and it worked fine. Are you setting `font-family: 'Raleway';` anywhere in the css?

Comment: Seems to work fine. See [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKujv). What browser are using?

Comment: Did you try these google fonts?

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cedarville+Cursive
or 
http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cedarville+Cursive

P.S.: Google fonts can slow down your page